# Ubuntu PPA with Pulse Audio 0.9.15?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, pulse-audio

Where can I find repository for Ubuntu jaunty 9.04 with Pulse Audio 0.9.15 (the one with working bluetooth)? I don't really want anything else, although if it has Skype working with bluetooth headset that would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search gives me this:

**Repository**

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/themuso/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/themuso/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
```

**Repository key**

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B88A1AA8
```

Comment: Thanks, last time I checked there was packages for Karmic Koala only